# How to Use Google Analytics in ReactJs Application to Track Events

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

I want to track link in component clicks using Google Analytics in my reactjs app. I did below steps:

1. npm install react-ga --save
2. import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
   ReactGA.initialize('UA-mytrackId');
3. my index.html has javascript code:

   var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
     ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
    });
    }

How to track the ,  clicks in my component below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link} from 'react-router-dom';
const CourseDetail=({course, onCourseSelect})=>{
return (    
   <div>
     {course.SUBJECT} {course.CATALOG_NBR} - {course.COURSE_DESCR} 
     <ViewLink onCourseSelect={onCourseSelect} course={course}></ViewLink>
     <Link  to={{ pathname: '/course/'+course.CLASS_NBR
             
            }}
            target="_blank"
                        key={course.ID} onClick={()=>"ga('create', 'UA-mytrackId'); ga('send',   'event', 'Schedule', 'bookmarksClick', 'bookmarks');"} >
                        Bookmark link
                    </Link>
    </div>  
);
};
export default CourseDetail;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example to send an event to Google Analytics in `React`:

```
const sendOutbound = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  ReactGA.event({
   category: 'Schedule',
   action: 'bookmarksClick',
   label: 'bookmarks'
 });

<a href... onClick={sendOutbound}>
   ...
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and got a lot of messages that I don't understand it. Does it mean it recorded the click event? "warn.js:2 [react-ga] `args.transport` must be either one of these values: `beacon`, `xhr` or `image`
warn @ warn.js:2
event @ core.js:510
sendOutbound @ CourseDetail.js:7
onClick @ react-router-dom.js:137
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:147
..."

Comment: Try to replace transport with label. See the code in my answer, I updated it.